# Usar ruta relativa en un FileInputStream

Tags: java, base-de-datos, spring-boot, maven

Tengo el siguiente código, en donde su función es crear la base de datos (que será recibido de un controller) y ejecuta un archivo `.sql` dentro de la base de datos creada para que importe tablas y procedimientos:

```
public void Restaurar_BD_SQL(CredencialesMySql cMysql, String NomBd,String ActBack) throws SQLException {                                              
        
        try {
             
            /* Crea la base de datos */
            Connection conx;
            conx = ConectarMySQL(cMysql);
            
            Statement stmt = conx.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("create database `" + NomBd + "`");
            
            System.out.println("Se creó BD " + NomBd);
            
             Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Q:/MySQL Server 8.0/bin/mysql -h " + cMysql.getNomServ() + " -u " + cMysql.getUsuario() + " -p" + cMysql.getClave() + " " + NomBd + "");
             OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();          
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ActBack);
             
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
             
             int leido = fis.read(buffer);
             
             while (leido > 0) {
                 os.write(buffer, 0 , leido);
                 leido = fis.read(buffer);
             }
             
             os.flush();
             fis.close();
             os.close();
             
             System.out.println("Fin del Proceso");
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Logger.getLogger(ejecutaSQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
      
    }
```

Y este es el controller que envía el parámetro a la función que les acabo de mencionar:

```
//llama a la conexión del servidor (cMysql), crea la base de datos ("xnomBD") y ejecuta el `.sql` (se especifica la ruta del SQL).
EjeSQL.Restaurar_BD_SQL(cMysql, xnomBD, "Q:\\sql\\Back_DEMO.sql");

//si logra conectarse para crear la DB, lanza 200 OK.
response.put("Mensaje", "Base de datos creada correctamente.");
```

Lo que necesito es que en esa ruta que defino en el controller, sea una ruta relativa y no absuluta, es decir, no llamar la ruta exacta del archivo (desde la raíz). Requiero de esto ya que mi proyecto se subirá a la nube y ahí no leerá nunca la ruta del archivo.

El archivo `.sql` lo puse en mi proyecto e intenté definir mi ruta así en mi local, pero no lo lee:

```
inputstream is = new FileInputStream("/Back_DEMO.sql");
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: como gestionas las dependencias? con ant, con maven, con gradle, etc?

Comment: buenos días, estoy utilizando maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por defecto, con el proposito de hacer inserciones a BDD Spring-Boot carga `data.sql` y/o `data-${platform}.sql` desde la carpeta de recursos `src/main/resources`

Puedes cambiar el nombre del script a cargar mediante:

```
spring.datasource.data=miscript.sql
```

y la plataforma mediante

```
spring.datasource.platform=oracle
```

para cargar la definicion del esquema tambien acepta `schema.sql` (que de hecho se lee antes de `data.sql`).

Puedes hallar mas al respecto en la [documentacion de spring-boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)